# Ruby on rails modelling relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model, relationships

I am creating a basic subscription application and am wondering what the cleanest way to model the relationships below would be. I seem to get confused with `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationships and when to use them.

I am trying to create roughly the structure below and a few points to note are. Both a `subscription` and an `order` can only have one `plan` but both `subscriptions` and `orders` can have many `products`.

A plan is also created in the same way as a product. i.e. 6 plans might be created which can then be added to any number of subscriptions (similar to a product).

**Relationships Design**
[image: Subscription Model Design]

Currently I have the following:

```
# User Model
has_one :subscription
has_one :plan, through: :subscription

# Subscription Model
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :plan # Not sure this is correct as a subscription should only be allowed to have 1 plan which belongs to the subscription. 

# Plan Model
has_many :subscriptions # Again this doesn't feel quite right as I think the plan should belong to the subscription.

# Product Model
has_and_belongs_to_many :orders
has_and_belongs_to_many :subscriptions

# Order Model
belongs_to :user
has_and_belongs_to_many :products
```

Any advice people can offer on the best way to model this would be much appreciated.

Comment: While you are writing the table definitions it usually is clear what relations you need. For example if you add `user_id` to `subscriptions` then `subscription` `belongs_to` `user`.

Comment: and if you cannot add a foreign_id to either of the tables, than it is a `has_and_belongs_to_many`

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me has_many :through association is more suitable.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

```
# User model
has_one :subscription
has_one :plan, through: :subscription

# Subscription model
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :plan
has_many :orders

# Plan (Subscription Plan) model
has_many :subscriptions
has_many :users, through: :subscriptions

# Order model
belongs_to :subscription
```

Can you elaborate on `Order` and `Product` models? What are you trying to make them represent? If `Order` is meant to represent each transaction on a subscription, it should belong to `Subscription`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Order should represent each transaction through a subscription as you mentioned. It's also worth mentioning that each customer can only have 1 subscription :). Thanks again for your advice

Comment: @TomPinchen Okay I updated my answer accordingly. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

If you just had to deal with `@plans`, I think the answer would be straightforward - you could just have `@subscriptions` and `@orders` belong to `@plans`, each of which could be defined to `have_many`:

```
# User model
has_one :subscription
has_many :orders

# Plan model
has_many :subscriptions
has_many :orders

# Subscription model
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :plan

# Order model
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :plan
```

(I appreciate your point about it "feeling" like a plan should belong to a subscription and not vice versa, but you have to 'use the force, Luke' a little here.)

I think the way perhaps to fold in `@products` might be to use join tables:

```
 # Order join table - OrderProduct
 belongs_to :order
 belongs_to :product

 # Subscription join table - SubscriptionProduct
 belongs_to :subscription
 belongs_to :product
```

Then, I think, the rest of the models look like:

```
# User model
has_one :subscription
has_many :orders    

# Plan model
has_many :subscriptions
has_many :orders

# Subscription model
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :plan
has_many :subscription_products
has_many :products, :through => :subscription_products

# Order model
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :plan
has_many :order_products
has_many :products, :through => :order_products

# Product model
has_many :subscription_products
has_many :subscriptions, :through => :subscription_products
has_many :order_products
has_many :orders, :through => :order_products
```

Creating a new `@order` might look something like:

```
 @order = Order.create(user: @user, plan: @plan)
 @order.products = @products
 @order.save
```

A new `@subscription` would be similar.

If you want a list of all `@users` subscribed to a given `@product`, you could:

```
@users = @product.subscriptions.map{|x| x.user}
```

If you want to see all `@products` currently subscribed to:

```
@products = @user.subscription.products
```

If you want to see all `@users` who have ever ordered a product:

```
@users = @product.orders.map{|x| x.user}.uniq
```

(`.uniq` in case a user has ordered the same product multiple times)

Answer (score 0):

**has_belongs_to_many** Specifies a many-to-many relationship with another class, ie instead of creating separate class for join table we can directly specify in those parent classes

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :abs
  .....
end

class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :abs
  ....
end

class AB < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :a
  belongs_to :b
  ....
end
```

instead of this we can directly specify in the class A and B like

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_belongs_to_many :as
  ....
end

class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_belongs_to_many :bs
  ....
end
```

Hope now it's clear about has_belongs_to_many association.

Now for the model design we have to keep Order class which specifically points to a user who ordered a product with a subscription
ie, `orders` table will act as join table which associate with the user, product, subscription.

> orders is a table which points to the Order Rails Model

**Rails Association will as follows**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :orders
  has_many plans, through: :subscription
  ....
end

class Plan < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :users, through: :subscriptions
  ....
end

class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :plan
  has_many :orders
  ....
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :subscription
  ....
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
  has_many :users, through: :orders
  ....
end
```

Hope this work for you :) .